# To which category does this algorithm belongs?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, boosting

I have came across the [Catboost](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/) package. Among the [classes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html) in categories in Sklearn, Catboost seems to belong to Ensemble methods. 
What are then the advantages of Catboost over AdaBoost, Bagging etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ensemble Methods** as defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning):

> In statistics and machine learning, ensemble methods use multiple
>   learning algorithms to obtain better predictive performance than could
>   be obtained from any of the constituent learning algorithms alone.

All those methods you mentioned are tree-based ensemble models:

- Bagging (Breiman, 1996): Fit many large trees to bootstrap-resampled versions of the training data, and classify by majority vote.
- Random Forests (Breiman 1999): Fancier version of bagging (only a subset of features are selected at random, unlike bagging where all features are considered for splitting a node).
- Boosting (Freund & Shapire, 1996): Fit many large or small trees to reweighted versions of the training data. Classify by weighted majority vote. There is a nice article explaining [gradient boosting trees](https://medium.com/mlreview/gradient-boosting-from-scratch-1e317ae4587d).

In general (in terms of prediction capability, boosting to be the best):

**Boosting > Random Forests > Bagging > Single Tree**

You might be wondering where *AdaBoost* fits?

**Adaptive Boosting** (or in short AdaBoost, was the first really successful boosting algorithm) works on improving the base learner esp. where it fails on predictions. Please note that the *base learner* can be any machine learning algorithms upon which the boosting is applied to obtain a strong learner. When *Decision stumps* are used as base learner, AdaBoost is comparable to the above-mentioned boosting trees. You might be asking, again, what are their differences, see below (taken from [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/statistics-machine-learning)):

[image]

**Modern Boosting Trees**

Due to the success of gradient boosting trees, there are types of boosting algorithms, namely: **Gradient Boosting, XGBoost, and Catboost**. They are conceptually very similar, yet they differ in e.g. sampling methods, regularizations, handling categorical features, performance etc. Strongly recommend checking [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/catboost-vs-light-gbm-vs-xgboost-5f93620723db) out if interested to learn more.

Personal Note: About 1.5 year ago I was a fan of XGBoost (for many reasons), till I experimented Catboost. Now I really like Catboost. First of all, it easily handles a mixture of numerical and categorical features EVEN without coding the categorical ones. And the default hyperparameters give comparable results to fine-tuned hyperparameters in XGBoost, thus less hassle. At present Catboost community is smaller than let's say XGboost, kind of makes it less attractive, but it is growing. Last note: I am not affiliated to any of these methods/implementations.

Hope, it is now better! ;-)

Comment: Very good links. These sites give impression that ensemble/boosting methods are superior to other methods such as Linear or Quadratic models, Support vector machines, Bayesian, Gaussian etc. It will be great if you can add a small note on comparison with these other methods.

Comment: It is hard to give me fair but concise comparison of these methods and making sure nothing is left out that is why I encouraged reading rather reaching out to single-person opinion. Anyway, I will add more details to my response, as concise as possible.